# Best Practice for handling dates between mySQL and V-Calendar using v-date-picker

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, vuejs2, datepicker

I'm using the V-Calendar v-date-picker to pick a single date to be stored in a date field in mySQL. I'm trying to figure out the best practice for handling dates between the two.

The v-date-picker documentation says that I can use v-model, which suggests I can bind the date from my database record (handled in vuex) right to the date picker. That date is delivered in the format 2019-09-15. When I try that, the v-date-picker simply ignores it and there is no date selected. The documentation indicates that it's best to use a native JavaScript date object so I try creating that. If I do that manually with a statically entered date, the date is selected on the picker, but I can't seem to figure out a good way to get the date from the database to apply to the picker. I can use a method to create a JS date object but I can't seem to get the date from the backend into the picker. If I use the js convert method I created in the v-model, it errors with 'unexpected token'.

I'm using Laravel and I've even tried converting the date on the back-end to date component values, but that didn't work either.

```js
<v-date-picker mode='single' v-if="schedule" v-model='schedule.start_at' :formats='formats' is-inline show-caps></v-date-picker>
```

Incidentally I'm using Laravel on the backend and vuex to manage state.

My convertDate function:

```js
convertDate(dt) {
  return new Date(dt)
},
```

**UPDATE**
I created an intermediate variable in the vuex store and when I load the database record I convert the date to a JavaScript date object and now it shows correctly in the component.

```js
SET_SCHED_DATE : (state,payload) => {
  state.sched_date = new Date(payload)
},
```

However, when I attempt to click another date in v-date-picker, it selects the prior day. I look at the vue inspector and the value has GMT -4. I'm guessing it's a UTC mismatch issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve. I tried converting my date to UTC in the vuex store with the code below, but I get a type mismatch error (I'm on v-calendar version 0.9.7). I even tried updating to version 1 (in beta) but it doesn't seem to install the necessary css so that creates other issues!

```
state.sched_date = new Date().toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I sorted it out. I updated to v-calendar version 1.0.0-beta.19. I'm still using a staging variable in a vuex called sched_date.

I'm using a Laravel Resource and before sending the data through the API I break the date into date component values using Carbon:

```
$carbondate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start_at, 'America/Los_Angeles');
'sched_date' => $carbondate->format('Y') . ', ' . $carbondate->format('m') . ', ' . $carbondate->format('d'),
```

I load my schedule data with the vuex action and then assign the value from the database to sched_date using a mutation.

```js
GET_SCHEDULE : async ({ state, commit }, schedule_id) => {
  let { data } = await axios.get('/api/schedules/'+schedule_id)
  commit('SET_SCHEDULE', data.data)
  commit('SET_SCHED_DATE', data.data.sched_date)
},
```

```js
SET_SCHED_DATE : (state,payload) => {
  state.sched_date = new Date(payload)
},
```

Next the v-date-picker in the vue template:

```
<v-date-picker mode='single' v-if="schedule" v-model="sched_date" is-inline show-caps></v-date-picker>
```

And finally in the save method, I convert the date to a mySQL friendly version:

```js
save() {
  var payload = { params: { id: this.schedule.id },  data: { 'start_at': this.$moment(this.sched_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") } }
  this.$store.dispatch('schedules/SAVE_SCHEDULE', payload).then(() => {
    Vue.toasted.show( 'Saved!', { type: 'success', duration: 5000 });
  });
},
```

I omitted the vuex save action for brevity.